# "As is Roland" VS "As Roland is"

Tags: word-order, inversion

Just a moment ago I heard a guy in a documentary utter the following sentence:

"It has both the Roland logo and the Moleko logo on it and I take both of those seriously as is Roland"

My question is: Why is the verb "to be" before "Roland" here? I mean - it's a positive sentence, isn't it? Then why the inversion?  Wouldn`t it be more correct to say "I take both of those seriously as Roland is" ?

Comment: Are you certain that that is what the guy says? Is there a person named Roland in addition to the brand? I ask because the sentence as you've written it doesn't really make sense to me.

Comment: Yup, I'm pretty sure the guy said those exact words. And I`m pretty sure that he is referring only to the Roland company

Comment: Then, perhaps the previous sentence is necessary, to give some context... Is it someone speaking to camera or someone reading a prepared script? Minor errors are made regularly in regular speech... also, how the sentence is stressed can change what it means... if you can find a clip of this that we can view, it would help a lot.

Comment: My question, though, is: In sentences of this type, what is the word correct word order? Do you say "I'm really into this kind of music as Mike is" or "I'm really into this kind of music as is Mike" ?

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/OfficialRolandAIRA/videos/1005850869474535/

Time: 9:01

Comment: They're actually both fine, though they have slightly different meanings... and their usage would be a bit different... For example, it'd be "I'm really into the same kind of music as Mike is [into]"... The second sentence is the same but there is a pause between music and as. In this case, it means that you're adding as an afterthought that Mike likes this music, too.

Comment: I don't mind posting this as an answer... but your question seems to be asking if the exact quote you have is correct English and, specifically, I have a lot of issues with it. The other example is much simpler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This guy is speaking off the cuff... he's clearly stumbling over his words a bit, trying to phrase what he's saying. I'd argue that what he means to say is:

> It has both the Roland logo and the Moleko logo on it and I take both of those seriously - as **does** Roland.

Or, if you change the tense of the entire sentence and make it into present progressive, you can use "is".

> ... I **am taking** both of these seriously - as is Roland.

This is the correct order for this phrase, regardless of the verb and tense used.

He could certainly, instead say:

> I take both of these seriously - and Roland does too.

But it is necessary to connect **what** Roland does to the previous thought. Without the word "too", or "also", or "as well", it leaves the reader or listener hanging.

By inverting the verb and noun and linking the clauses, you're creating that same connection.

> I like rock music, as does Michael.
>   I am having fun, as is Martha.

This serves to mean the same thing as:

> I like rock music. Michael likes rock music.
>   I am having fun. Martha is having fun.

Comment: I think I get it. Is it safe to say that the proper word order in this kind of structure is: As + auxillary verb + subject? 
As in: "I bought a couple of donuts as did James". Or: "I was upset with the whole situation as was Martha" ;)

Comment: @IGO Perfect! That's exactly correct. It may not **always** work but both of those examples are good.

Comment: BUT: When "as" is used in the expression "Same as", the proper word order should be something like:  "I`m using the same software as Mike is" , right?

Comment: @IGO  So, what I have in my answer that you don't have in your comments, is a divider between the two parts of the sentence. Either a dash or a comma will tell them that you've created a pause. "*I'm using the same software - as is Mike*" is fine... but it means something different. It would often be preceded by something like "*Janice is using PowerPoint.*" (possibly said by a different person) In this case, the end result is that all three of you are using PowerPoint.

Comment: @IGO That being said, your construction, on its own, is correct, too... but you wouldn't use any pauses because it's a single thought, whereas the other type of sentence is two connected thoughts.

Comment: I totally get it now. 

FIRST EXAMPLE: "Kate is doing  the same thing as Jimmy is" - one sentence, meaning that one person is doing the same thing the other person is doing, basically. 

SECOND EXAMPLE: "Kate is doing the same thing over and over" ... "as is Jimmy" meaning that Kate is doing the same thing over and over.   "...and Jimmy is, too" or "so is Jimmy".

Am I right? :)

Comment: @IGO Yes. That is correct.